# Query Wikidata for all attributes based on name

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want that given an object name, to write a Sparql query which queries Wikidata for all the attributes of the resulted object. For example:

```
SELECT ?thing 
where
{
  ?thing schema:name "Pyramid"@en
}
```

Will return 2 urls:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pyramid
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid

but none of those urls is pointing to: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q12516

Is `schema:name` the right predicate to use for querying the name? How should this query be written in order to receive the url to `Q12516` (Wikidata item for pyramid)?

Comment: `rdfs:label`; https://w.wiki/EYc for more info.

Comment: `rdfs:label` or for alias `skos:altLabel`